# Translating IPv6 header to IPv4 in linux

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, router, ipv6

Simple question I hope:

We have a IPv6 only local network. We want to be able to send data to an IPv4 only server on the internet. (One direction is enough, to send UDP packets).

The data arrives to the router in a IPv6 packet, with destination set to an IPv6 representation of the servers IPv4 address.
What I gather is that we would "only" need to take the content from inside the packet and slap an IPv4 header on it.

What software / configuration I need for this? The router box is running Ubuntu 16.04.

And please we are not network experts hehe .. so try to keep it easy. Subtle terminology differences etc will be lost (like "IPv4 embedded address" and "IPv4 compatible address" - they all look like the same thing from a distance)

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Can you provide an actual example of the addresses being used? How are they obtained -- anything like DNS64, or just putting the 32 bits into the address field?

Comment: I assume you have a single public IPv4 address on your router (or your ISP), and you want to use that for several clients in your local network? If yes, google for [NAT64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT64).

Answer (score 2):

What you want is running NAT64 on your Linux router. It will determine the destination IPv4 address my looking at the last 32 bits of the IPv6 address and NAT traffic there.

I can recommend [Jool](https://www.jool.mx/en/index.html), an well-maintained open source NAT64 and SIIT implementation.